# Расположение в шапке в линию

Tags: html, css

```css
.header {
  background: rgba(18, 93, 175, 0.0);
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 315px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.logo {
  font-family: "A_La_Russ", sans-serif;
  src: url('../A_La_Russ.ttf');
  background: rgba(128, 74, 19, 0.8);
  height: 275px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  width: 1223px;
}

.logotip {
  width: 335px;
  height: 275px;
  background: url('../images/logo.png')no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  float: left;
}

.logo p {
  color: #ffb015;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-shadow: #ea690b 1px 1px 0, #ea690b -1px -1px 0, #ea690b -1px 1px 0, #ea690b 1px -1px 0;
}

.up p {
  padding-left: 351px;
}

.centr p {
  padding-left: 390px;
}

.down p {
  padding-left: 485px;
}

.grup {
  width: 300px;
  height: 275px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="logotip"> </div>
    <div class="up">
      <p>Храм</p>
    </div>
    <div class="centr">
      <p>Воскресения</p>
    </div>
    <div class="down">
      <p>Словущего</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grup"></div>
  </div>
```

нужно div class"grup" расположить в одну линию с остальными.

Comment: С кем именно состальными? Я чего-то не вижу тут что-бы кто-то в один ряд стоял

Comment: logotip слева, up centr down в центре, grup справа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пытаюсь Ванговать ...

```css
.header {
  background: rgba(18, 93, 175, 0.0);
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 315px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.logo {
  font-family: "A_La_Russ", sans-serif;
  src: url('../A_La_Russ.ttf');
  background: rgba(128, 74, 19, 0.8);
}

.logotip {
  background: url('../images/logo.png')no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.logo p {
  color: #ffb015;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-shadow: #ea690b 1px 1px 0, #ea690b -1px -1px 0, #ea690b -1px 1px 0, #ea690b 1px -1px 0;
}

img{
  display:block;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="logotip"> 
      <img src="https://img.favcars.com/saab/logotypes/saab_logotypes__wallpapers_1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
   </div>
  
  <div class="items">
      <div class="up">
         <p>Храм</p>
      </div>
      <div class="centr">
        <p>Воскресения</p>
      </div>
      <div class="down">
        <p>Словущего</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  
 <div class="grup">group</div>
  
  </div>
```